# pyodbc will only execute commands when querying the database specified in the connection string

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, pyodbc

```
conn = pyodbc.connect(r'DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};SERVER=localhost\<redacted>;DATABASE=master;UID=<redacted>;PWD=<redacted>')
cursor = conn.cursor()
query = """SELECT <redacted> FROM <redacted> WHERE <redacted>"""
row = cursor.execute(query).fetchone()
dummyName = row[0]
cursor.close()

cursor = conn.cursor()
query = """SELECT <redacted> FROM <redacted> WHERE <redacted>"""
print query
row = cursor.execute(query)
print row.fetchone()
```

This code properly connects to the db and executes the first query on the first db. However, when it executes the second query on the other db, it doesn't return any data and I get a popup window saying python.exe has stopped working when I try to fetch any rows, after which my program crashes. I checked and the query I'm trying to execute is a valid query that works properly from the master db and from the same account I'm connected to in the code.

Comment: Are you able to connect to your SQL server with the database in question in the connection string?

Comment: Yes. Apparently we were using an old version of pyodbc. I updated it and now the code works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was we were using an old version of pyodbc. I updated it to the new version and now it works perfectly.